# Does an Activity extending another activity have 2 separate contexts for super and child classes(Activities) Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, oop, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have a template Activity class as

```
open class AbstractActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
  onCreate()
  ...
}
```

I will be using this template AbstractActivity for almost every Activity in my project

I have an Activity as :

```
class MyActivity : AbstractActivity(){


}
```

On debugging what I have understood is that both have 2 separate contexts instead of one.

When I call `finish()` inside `onActivityResult` in `AbstractActivity` I am closing abstract activity only but not the `MyActivity`.

From my understanding as per OOPS `finish()` call here must close the whole `MyActivity` extending `AbstractActivity` right but why is only `AbstractActivity` being finished.

P.S : I am calling `finish()` from `AbstractActivity`'s `onActivityResult` method

Comment: This is not really how object-oriented programming works. There is no such thing as standalone `AbstractActivity`, which is separate to `MyActivity`. They are a single entity. Using the typical analogy to animals, this is like saying you fed the animal of the dog, but not the dog itself. How do you observe that "only AbstractActivity being finished"?

Comment: "On debugging what I have understood is that both have 2 separate contexts instead of one." This is definitely wrong. One activity instance, one context.

Comment: @broot
Can you tell me the reason for this behavior in my case?

Comment: What behavior? You didn't really explain the behavior you observe. I asked for this explicitly in my previous comment, but you didn't provide any details. You said that `AbstractActivity` is finished alone, but that sounds vague. `AbstractActivity` doesn't even exist as a separate object, so how could we finish something that doesn't exist? It is unclear what do you mean without a further explanation on what exactly you do and observe.

Comment: Or maybe you actually instantiate a separate `AbstractActivity` object, because in your example it is not really abstract, so it can be instantiated. But we can only guess.

Answer (score -2):

When you call `finish()` inside `onActivityResult()` in the **AbstractActivity**, it should finish the instance of **AbstractActivity** itself. However, it will not directly affect the instance of **MyActivity** that inherits from it. If you're seeing the **AbstractActivity** being finished, but the **MyActivity** is still running, this is expected behavior as Both activity has different lifecycles on their own.

The `finish()` method is used to finish the current activity instance, which means it will remove the activity from the activity stack and destroy it. Since you're calling `finish()` inside AbstractActivity, it will finish that particular instance of `AbstractActivity`, leaving the MyActivity running if it's still in the foreground.

If you want to finish **MyActivity** then you have to call `finish()` explicitly in this activity as well.

Comment: @ MuzammalAbdulGhafoor 

When MyActivity is extending AbstractActivity how is the whole activity not getting destroyed.What is the reason for not finishing of whole activity when calling finish from abstract activity?

Comment: @PranayAvvaru This answer is completely wrong and doesn’t make sense with regards to OOP. Don’t be confused by it. An instance of something is only one instance--there are not separate instances of all its superclasses floating around that can be treated distinctly.